# Passing values from Rails to SASS using custom functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I'm trying to pass some values from Rails (3.2.12) to SASS (3.2.7) files during compile time. I've tried to follow the [SASS docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#defining_custom_sass_functions) and some other [answers](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#defining_custom_sass_functions) on SO. It seems like it should be quite straightforward but I haven't managed to get past this error:

```
undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
  (in /home/joegatt/Sites/joegatt.net/v3/joegattnet_v3/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass)
```

My set-up is:

```
#/config/application.rb
if config.respond_to?(:sass)
  require "#{config.root}/lib/sass.rb"
end


#/lib/sass.rb
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def styling(string, opts = {} )
    assert_type string, :String
    Sass::Script::String.new( '#ff0000' )
  end
  declare :styling, :args => [:string]
end


#/assets/stylesheets/default.css.scss
background-color: styling('test')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it to work by doing the following:

```
#/lib/sass.rb
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def settings_styling(setting)
    assert_type setting, :String
    Sass::Script::Parser.parse('#ff0000', 0, 0)
  end
  declare :settings_styling, args: [:setting]
end
```

The difference is that instead of using Sass::Script::String.new, I use Sass::Script::Parser.parse so that instead of a string a "[tree of Script::Nodes](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Parser.html)" is returned. Any better ideas?